# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException for unknown reason

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that creates a maze as a 2d array. I've run into a hiccup, and that is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. It is pointing to `maze[0][0] = "S"` in the drawMaze method. I'm scratching my head at this, I have no idea why it's throwing an error.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class LA2_MazeSolver {

private int rows;
private int cols;
private String[][] maze = new String[rows][cols];

LA2_MazeInput mi = new LA2_MazeInput();

public void setNumRows(int numRows) {

    this.rows = numRows;

}

public void setNumCols(int numCols) {

    this.cols = numCols;

}

public int getNumRows() {

    return this.rows;

}

public int getNumCols() {

    return this.cols;

}

public void drawMaze() {

    Random r = new Random();

    maze[0][0] = "S";
    maze[rows - 1][cols - 1] = "D";
    int limit = ((rows * cols) / 3);

    for (int i = r.nextInt(limit) + 1; i < limit; i++) {

        maze[r.nextInt(rows) - 1][r.nextInt(cols) - 1] = "#";

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < maze.length; i++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < maze[0].length; c++) {

            if (!(maze[i][c].matches("#")) && !(maze[i][c].matches("S")) && !(maze[i][c].matches("D"))) {

                maze[i][c] = Integer.toString(r.nextInt(100) + 1);

            }

        }
    }

}

public void printMaze() {

}

/*public boolean isSolvable() {

    return solveMazeRecursively(this.rows, this.cols);

}

private boolean solveMazeRecursively(int row, int col) {

}*/

public void printResult() {

}
}
```

Comment: `maze` is being initialized while `rows` is `0` and has not yet been set. The `maze` needs to be initialized only once `rows` and `cols` has been set.

Comment: You need to initialize maze at the top of your program or in your constructor before it can be assigned a value. Change rows and cols to a specific int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Java, you can't make a definition like `private String[][] maze = new String[rows][cols];` outside of the constructor. At that point in the the code, the value for `row` and `col` have not been defined and so something like `private String[][] maze = new String[rows][cols];` won't have well defined behaviour (`row` and `col` may in fact be 0, who knows).

Try instead something like this:

```
    private int row;
    private int col;
    private String[][] maze;

    public LA2_MazeSolver(int row, int col) {
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        maze = new String[row][col]
    }
```

Now when you create a `LA2_MazerSolver` object, you will dynamically create an array of the correct size to use (for example `solver = new LA2_MazeSolver(row, col)`).

Comment: This is really helpful but I'm stuck on the fact that the values of row and col are passed on by another class LA2_MazeInput. I can't hard code the values of them. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Create a get function in your other class? row = LA2_MazeInput.getRow();

Comment: @GregSmith Do you not know how to use the constructor? I through that response together quickly but I guess I should have been more thorough. you can pass arguments into an object when you create it using its constructor method. Hang on, I'll edit my post.

Comment: @JohnDengis The problem I'm having is that I'm required to use getters and setters. Using a constructor would make those methods redundant, therefore I'm pretty sure I need to do it the hard way

Comment: @GregSmith I don't understand why you can't use a constructor if it solves the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. You are getting the Array Index Out of Bound exception because you are exceeding the array boundaries.

> I've run into a hiccup, and that is ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. It is pointing to "maze[0][0] = "S";"

You have declared maze in the following block

```
private int rows;
private int cols;
private String[][] maze = new String[rows][cols];
```

Note that you are specifying a size of 'rows' and 'cols' for 'maze'. But these values are 0 and 0 respectively. See that you are not giving a value to rows and cols at the time of initialization. So the default value of int primitives declared as class members is 0.

To fix this problem, initialize rows and cols to a value greater than 0.